# Get the number of div with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am working on a real-time page which display new very small colored div every second.
The color can be green, orange or red.

[image: Colored div]

I would like to add a tooltip on `mouseover` over a color to display the number of div it contains.

I would have simply used this

```
$(".myClass").length
```

but the color can be shown multiple time on the line

[image]

In this case, I need to know the number of div inside the first orange section and inside the second orange section

*For example :*

Green - 2

Orange - 4

Green - 5

Red - 4

Orange - 2

Green - 2

**AngularJS - Controller**

I am using AngularJS which retrieve those data from an API. I receive a JSON array of string.

```
colors : ["0", "2", "3"] //0:red - 2:green - 3:orange
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="s in d.colors track by $index" class="status-box" ng-class="{'redStatus' : s == '0', 'greenStatus' : s == '2', 'orangeStatus' : s == '3'}"></div>
```

Is there a way to add it directly from the controller ? I need a fast function that can be done/refreshed every second when new data arrive

**EDIT**

I am using Semantic UI thus I just have to add    `data-tooltip="x"` to a div or span or other to display the tooltip. `x` should be replaced by the number of div

**HTML GENERATED**

```
<div ng-repeat="c in l.colors track by $index" class="status-box ng-scope greenStatus" data-tooltip="TESTING" ng-class="{'redStatus' : c == '0', 'greenStatus' : c == '2', 'orangeStatus' : c == '3'}"></div>
<div ng-repeat="c in l.colors track by $index" class="status-box ng-scope greenStatus" data-tooltip="TESTING" ng-class="{'redStatus' : c == '0', 'greenStatus' : c == '2', 'orangeStatus' : c == '3'}"></div>
<div ng-repeat="c in l.colors track by $index" class="status-box ng-scope orangeStatus" data-tooltip="TESTING" ng-class="{'redStatus' : c == '0', 'greenStatus' : c == '2', 'orangeStatus' : c == '3'}"></div>
<div ng-repeat="c in l.colors track by $index" class="status-box ng-scope orangeStatus" data-tooltip="TESTING" ng-class="{'redStatus' : c == '0', 'greenStatus' : c == '2', 'orangeStatus' : c == '3'}"></div>
<div ng-repeat="c in l.colors track by $index" class="status-box ng-scope orangeStatus" data-tooltip="TESTING" ng-class="{'redStatus' : c == '0', 'greenStatus' : c == '2', 'orangeStatus' : c == '3'}"></div>
<div ng-repeat="c in l.colors track by $index" class="status-box ng-scope orangeStatus" data-tooltip="TESTING" ng-class="{'redStatus' : c == '0', 'greenStatus' : c == '2', 'orangeStatus' : c == '3'}"></div>
<div ng-repeat="c in l.colors track by $index" class="status-box ng-scope greenStatus" data-tooltip="TESTING" ng-class="{'redStatus' : c == '0', 'greenStatus' : c == '2', 'orangeStatus' : c == '3'}"></div>
<div ng-repeat="c in l.colors track by $index" class="status-box ng-scope greenStatus" data-tooltip="TESTING" ng-class="{'redStatus' : c == '0', 'greenStatus' : c == '2', 'orangeStatus' : c == '3'}"></div>
<div ng-repeat="c in l.colors track by $index" class="status-box ng-scope greenStatus" data-tooltip="TESTING" ng-class="{'redStatus' : c == '0', 'greenStatus' : c == '2', 'orangeStatus' : c == '3'}"></div>
<div ng-repeat="c in l.colors track by $index" class="status-box ng-scope greenStatus" data-tooltip="TESTING" ng-class="{'redStatus' : c == '0', 'greenStatus' : c == '2', 'orangeStatus' : c == '3'}"></div>
<div ng-repeat="c in l.colors track by $index" class="status-box ng-scope greenStatus" data-tooltip="TESTING" ng-class="{'redStatus' : c == '0', 'greenStatus' : c == '2', 'orangeStatus' : c == '3'}"></div>
```

Comment: // get the number of elements with class myclass
var count = $('.myclass').length;

Comment: As I said, this does not solve my problem. The colors can be splitted in different part

Comment: Do you need the serial number or the amount?

Comment: The amount of div inside each color.
Example for the second image : 
Green : 2 -
Orange : 5 -
Green : 6 - 
Red : 5 - 
Orange : 3 -
Green : 2 -

Comment: provide full html code

Comment: What do you mean ? I only have a ng-repeat inside a div. There is nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Heres, what you can try using [jQuery](https://www.jquery.com)

## JS

```
var c = 0;
function countChildsByClass(className) {
    var n = 0,
        array = [];
    n = $('.' + className)[c].children.length;
    array.push(n);
    c++;
    return array;
}
console.log(countChildsByClass('orangeDIV')); //Outputs array [5, 3] = [child in first orangeDIV, child in second orangeDIV]
```

## HTML

```
<div class="orangeDIV">
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
</div>
<div class="orangeDIV">
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
</div>
```

> You can get only first `orangeDIV`'s children by using `countChildsByClass('orangeDIV')[0]`

Comment: i haven't  tested it, so share any error comes with it.

Comment: My HTML is not structured like this